# How to Auto load info to label while open .app by swift code

Tags: swift, string, startup, var

I am starting to learn swift code, with this code after entering your name and pressing the button will appear greeting information.  I want to not need to press the button, when I open the application, can it run this code by itself?  with the words "Hello World!"

```
var name = nameField.stringValue
if name.isEmpty {
  name = "World"
}
let greeting = "Hello \(name)!"
helloLabel.stringValue = greeting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code into [`viewDidLoad`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621495-viewdidload).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    ...
}
```